# TravisCi loses connection at Test Suite

Tags: laravel, travis-ci

I'm attempting to find out why when my testsuite reaches it fails on the very first test saying that the database has lost connection when running my testsuite from my Laravel application.

```
The command "php artisan key:generate" exited with 0.
31.27s$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit Pretty Result Printer 0.19.14 by Codedungeon and contributors.
==> Configuration:~/build/me/app/vendor/codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer/phpunit-printer.yml
PHPUnit 7.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
 ==> Tests\Feature\Module\MyTest⚈
Time: 31.12 seconds, Memory: 24.00MB
There was 1 error:
1) Tests\Feature\Module\Test::my_test_method
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection     timed out (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Caused by
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out
```

.travis.yml

```
language: php

php:
  - 7.1

services:
  - mysql  

before_script:
  - cp .env.travis .env
  - mysql -e 'CREATE DATABASE my_database;'
  - composer self-update
  - composer install --no-interaction
  - php artisan key:generate
  - php artisan migrate 

script:
  - vendor/bin/phpunit

cache:
  directories:
    - vendor
```

.env.travis

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=my_database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=array
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

The following only include lines that I've changed or added to these files.

```
phpunit.xml
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="my_database"/>
```

config/database.php

```
'mysql_testing' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_TESTING', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_TESTING', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_TESTING', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB',
    ],
```

Comment: What is the code in `my_test_method`?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to with actual individual tests methods because if I remove that test method then it just does the same for the next method. Currently have it set to stop on first failure however when I set that to false and run the whole test suite it gives me the same error for every test.

Comment: Yeah, ok.  Your travis config is pretty simple so I don't see anything that would cause this in what you've posted.  Have you altered anything with the database config in this project? What's your phpunit.xml file have for database settings?

Comment: I'm going to update this post with additional file changes.

Comment: You posted a mysql_testing connection config but you aren't using that connection.

Comment: Ah okay so would I need to add that to my phpunit.xml file AND my DB_CONNECTION env variable for .env.travis file.